# How can i run casperjs script from python on ubuntu?

Tags: python, ubuntu, casperjs

I would like to run casperjs from python on zorin os 11. I have researched about that topic but i can not figure it out exactly because there is lack of information as far as i can see. So, how can i do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried the obvious solution? I mean, did you try the following?

```
import os
os.system('<your ubuntu code>')
```

For several issues, this 'os' library solve the problem.

Comment: No i didnt try it. Because i dont know actual structure of the implementation code.

Comment: I finally achieve this. 
os.system("casperjs \
    --engine=slimerjs \
     /home/username/Desktop/yidigim.js \
")

Answer (score 0):

Selenium + PhantomJS is your solution (more info http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/)

```
from selenium import webdriver

browser = webdriver.PhantomJS()
browser.get("www.yourURL.com")
```

Comment: I dont want to use selenium. Is there any solution ?

Comment: Can I know Why not?

Comment: Because i would like to use casperjs with engine slimerjs. This is why i dont want